# cartThrob - Discount by Channel

Tags: cartthrob, discounts

I was wondering if there is a way or a plugin that I can apply a discount to a product that is related to another channel.

Basically the same way that 'Percentage Off Categories' type works.

On my site there are products that have a relationship with a channel called 'Maker'. This channel shows who made the product.

What I want, this that any product that is made by this 'Maker' to automatically discount 25%.

Is there any way of doing this using Discounts? Or will I have to take of the price manually for each product?

Many thanks,

Hugh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a "Maker" relationship field, what if you created a new "Maker" category group and then assign the products to the appropriate maker category? Then you could use the 'Percentage Off Categories' discount.